# How to prevent resized featured images?

Tags: images

The theme has set thumbnail sizes for featured images:

```
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size( 'hitmag-landscape', 1120, 450, true );
add_image_size( 'hitmag-featured', 735, 400, true );
add_image_size( 'hitmag-grid', 348, 215, true );
add_image_size( 'hitmag-list', 290, 220, true );
add_image_size( 'hitmag-thumbnail', 135, 93, true );
```

How do I set the "featured" image one so that the image size is just whatever image I upload (for height - I want to be able to set width to 735 still)

Comment: If u dont want to crop image than you can change **true** to **false** in this line **add_image_size( 'hitmag-featured', 735, 400, true );**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Featured image sizes are mostly likely controlled by your theme, so I would look there.  Maybe there is a theme setting for it.

You can also check the following setting to see if it us using one of those sizes.

[image]

---

You can change the featured image size by adding this code into your functions.php file.  [More info on set_post_thumbnail_size](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size).

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 500, 500 );
```

---

You can also add a new image size and then use it in your template by doing something like this...

```
add_image_size( 'featured-image-size', 800, 9999 ); // Add to functions.php
php the_post_thumbnail( 'featured-image-size' ); // Template usage
```

More info on [add_image_size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) & [the_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/)

---

**Edit:** Since you updated your question, here is an updated answer.

You can set the height to be unlimited like this...

```
add_image_size( 'hitmag-featured', 735, 9999 );
```